# Slick SQLite setting PRAGMAS

Tags: sqlite, scala, slick, pragma

I'm trying to set a busy timeout to my database to cope with concurrency issues. I'm using SQLite and Slick as the database. To set the PRAGMA I use:

```
StaticQuery.updateNA("PRAGMA busy_timeout=1000").execute
```

And to verify I tried

```
println(StaticQuery.updateNA("PRAGMA busy_timeout").list.head)
```

But it prints 0 when it should print 1000.

I tried using the sqlu"PRAGMA......".execute as well but it didn't work either.

Any Ideas how I can get around this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you executing both in the same session?